# Django server not sending logs to Logstash

Tags: python, django, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using ELK stack for centralised logging from my Django server. My ELK stack is on a remote server and `logstash.conf` looks like this:

```
input {
    tcp {
    port => 5959
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["xx.xx.xx.xx:9200"]
  }
}
```

Both services elasticsearch and logstash are working (checked using `docker-compose logs logstash`).

My Django server's settings file has logging configured as below:

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'handlers': {
        'logstash': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logstash.TCPLogstashHandler',
            'host': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
            'port': 5959, # Default value: 5959
            'version': 0, # Version of logstash event schema. Default value: 0 (for backward compatibility of the library)
            'message_type': 'django',  # 'type' field in logstash message. Default value: 'logstash'.
            'fqdn': True, # Fully qualified domain name. Default value: false.
            'tags': ['django.request'], # list of tags. Default: None.
        },
  },
  'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['logstash'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
  },
}
}
```

I run my Django server and Logstash handler handles the logs as console shows no logs. I used the `python-logstash` library in Django server to construct the above conf, but the logs are not sent to my remote server.

I checked through many questions, verified that services are running and ports are correct, but I have no clue why the logs are not being sent to Logstash.

Comment: Are you sure that "django.request" doesn't filter out all events?

Comment: Django request is supposed to send all the requests logs

Comment: Have you tried change the `fqdn` to `False`?

Comment: Yep tried but it did not work as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the configuration, logger "django.request" is set to level "DEBUG" and the handler "logstash" is set to level "INFO". My guess is that the **handler** will not process **DEBUG** messages. I'm not sure though.

Set the same level for the logger and the handler to test that it works.

What level to use depends on what you want from your logs. In this case I guess level INFO would suffice.

If not already take a look at [Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#module-django.utils.log)

NOTE: From comments it seems not to solve the problem but I hope it is useful anyway.

UPDATE:

I tried the following configuration and it catches 404 and 500 errors in the "debug.log".

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'logfile': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'debug.log'),
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}}
```

With this test configuration the logstash handler should at least receive the message/logrecord. If no luck I suggest to try debug the [logstash.TCPLogstashHandler](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash/blob/master/logstash/handler_tcp.py#L7) and the
[SocketHandler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L623) (inherited by TCPLogstashHandler) to make sure they receive the emitted record.

Comment: Your point seems to be correct so what would you suggest for solving this?

Comment: I suggested to use level INFO. Depending on how log messages are created, sometimes it's good to be able to switch DEBUG logging on and off depending which environment is used. For instance django uses it for mail_admins.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki `django.request` logging just `WARNING` and `ERROR` messages.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-request-logger

Comment: @ArpitSolanki What messages are you trying to log?

Comment: tried this answer with producing errors like 404, 500 but did not work

Comment: @DanielBackman Thanks for your effort but it did not solve the problem. I can still award you the bounty if you add a small note to your answer that it did not solve the problem but helped in logging part of the code

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I'll try to find why the logger is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue but after scrambling around a lot, I made it work by changing `django.request` to `django.server`.
I got the idea when I used only `django` as a logger name in the python code and then found out the actual `logger_name` from log data stored in elasticsearch.
Below is the updated code

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'handlers': {
        'logstash': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logstash.TCPLogstashHandler',
            'host': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
            'port': 5959, # Default value: 5959
            'version': 0, # Version of logstash event schema. Default value: 0 (for backward compatibility of the library)
            'message_type': 'django',  # 'type' field in logstash message. Default value: 'logstash'.
            'fqdn': True, # Fully qualified domain name. Default value: false.
            'tags': ['django.request'], # list of tags. Default: None.
        },
  },
  'loggers': {
        'django.server': {  # Here is the change
            'handlers': ['logstash'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
      }
  },
}
```

Refer to this for more detail on django logging
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#id3

Comment: so later should I do this before logging `logging.getLogger('django.server')` ? the `.` is confusing me

Answer (score 0):

Your logging configuration is correct. 
You need to mention index name in elasticsearch config part of logstash conf. Update your logstash config to

```
input {
    tcp {
    port => 5959
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["xx.xx.xx.xx:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "djangologs"
  }
}
```

If you are using google cloud or AWS, open port/update firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tasneem,

This worked on my machine:

mysite/settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'handlers': {
      'logstash': {
          'level': 'DEBUG',
          'class': 'logstash.TCPLogstashHandler',
          'host': 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
          'port': 9600, # Default value: 5959
          'version': 1, # Version of logstash event schema. Default value: 0 (for backward compatibility of the library)
          'message_type': 'django',  # 'type' field in logstash message. Default value: 'logstash'.
          'fqdn': False, # Fully qualified domain name. Default value: false.
          'tags': ['django.request'],# list of tags. Default: None.
      },
  },
  'loggers': {
      'django.server': {
          'handlers': ['logstash'],
          'level': 'DEBUG',
      },
  },
}
```

logstash# cat logstash-django.conf

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 9600
    codec => json
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["https://your.elasticsearch.com:port"]
      user => ["xx"]
      password => ["xx"]
      index => "djangotest"
      document_type => "%{type}"
    }
   stdout {
      codec => rubydebug {metadata => true }
  }
}
```